# Cannot Install R Studio on Anaconda Navigator on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, rstudio

So, I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04. I installed R without a problem. However, when I try to install R Studio on Anaconda Navigator, I cannot do it. After I click install R Studio, no matter how long I wait it doesn't install.

Loading Packages of /home/computername/anaconda3...

That is what it says. Moreover, loading bar just keeps repeating itself, nothing happens. It only happens in my UBUNTU OS. I did not have this problem on other operating systems.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I used "Stacer" to clean the Application caches. Now Rstudio is installed, but it is in an other environment than the "base(root)" environment.
But I used
`conda install -c r r-irkernel`
in the base environment, and now I have the R kernel in Jupyter-notebook.